# What does the Starfleet insignia represent?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-insignias

A consistent part of the Starfleet uniforms in the Star Trek shows and movies has been some version of this insignia:

[image: starfleet logo]

I originally thought this was a stylized letter "A", but that doesn't really make sense.

**What is this symbol supposed to represent?**

Comment: It looks like a stylized golden triangle to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_triangle_(mathematics)#/media/File:Golden_triangle_and_Fibonacci_spiral.svg

Comment: @dev_willis Interesting!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is my understanding that the symbol is a stylized version of the NASA emblem of our time. [image: Emblem]

[Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_insignia) also leans towards a connection between Star Trek and the NASA badge:

> In a form of fact emulating fiction (and vice-versa), the US Air Force
>   Space Command badges have a delta arrowhead very similar to the
>   1960s-designed Enterprise insignia, while the 22nd century Starfleet
>   insignia seems to be a deliberate synthesis between the TOS era
>   pennant and the NASA logo.

Answer (score 72):

This has been retconned over the years.  This is the most current version, that I know of:

This is the NASA insignia:

[image: NASA Insignia]

This is the United Earth Starfleet insignia (in the 2150s, ENT-era):

[image: United Earth Starfleet]

These are the TNG-DS9-VOY-era Starfleet insignias:

[image: TNG-era] [image: DS9-era] [image: Alpha Quadrant VOY-era]

And one further variation from the future:

[image: 29th Century Starfleet]

---

Originally, this was Starfleet's insignia in the TOS era (no explanation given):

[image: TOS Starfleet]

---

The truth is, the symbol we all know was originally the assignment patch for Kirk's Enterprise.  In that era, each ship had their own symbol, and the pennant seen above was Starfleet's.  The Enterprise symbol was later adopted for all of Starfleet in recognition of that five-year mission (in-universe).  For alternate examples:

This is Admiral James Komack, wearing the Starfleet [admiral patch/pin of that time](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_ranks#Flag_officers):

[image: James Komack]

This is Commodore Matt Decker, former captain of the [USS Constellation](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Constellation_(NCC-1017)), wearing the insignia for his ship:

[image: Matt Decker]

From left to right, these are the assignment patches for the [USS Exeter](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Exeter_(NCC-1672)), the [USS Defiant](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Defiant_(NCC-1764)), and finally, the [USS Enterprise](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701)):

[image: Exeter] [image: Defiant] [image: Enterprise]

And there's a [whole lot more](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Assignment_patch), in every era prior to TNG.

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Comment: Wow.  I never realized the [Defiant-class Defiant](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Defiant_%282370%29) was named for a Constitution-class ship. Awesome stuff!

Comment: Love that shot of Spock and Bones. Looks like everyone's waiting for their appointment with Dr. Shiny Boomerang.

Comment: The "TNG-DS9-VOY-era Starfleet insignias" (excluding the one from the TOS movie era) represents what the *communicators* of that timeframe look like, which do not necessarily match the "pure emblem". For that purpose, it is interesting to look at the hull markings from the respective eras: The [Enterprise 1701-D](http://www.pntmodels.com/decals/galdetail.jpg) does feature the arrowhead with the oval, whereas [Voyager](http://p2.la-img.com/1034/22122/7703152_5_l.jpg) *only* has the arrowhead, not the angular shape found in the communicator.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper No, those are the emblems.  The background part has been included much of the time they appear.  [From Ex Astris Scientia](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/federation_emblem.htm), for example, [Harry Kim's Starfleet certificate uses the third one](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/federation_emblem/2372-certificate-nonsequitur.jpg)

Comment: Or perhaps adopted by all of Starfleet because it is the only one that isn't totally fugly.

Comment: Actually, the delta patch was supposed to represent assignment to _any_ starship, not specifically the _Enterprise_. The _Exeter_ patches were a production mistake, and the _Defiant_ uniforms we actually saw onscreen in "The Tholian Web" all had the same patch as the _Enterprise_. https://www.startrek.com/article/starfleet-insignia-explained

Answer (score 13):

I vaguely remember a Star Trek novel named "Federation" where both the TOS and TNG Enterprises are involved with Zephram Cochrane and in that novel a decsription of the insignia was given based on the physics of the warp drive.

In that book, the insignia represents how warp drive sidesteps relativistic mass dilation. The top curve represents the energy required to continue accelerating at near-light speeds, which approaches infinity. IF you could somehow exceed the speed of light, that would then work backwards (higher energy would result in you moving slower. Time would also run in reverse.). The lower curve represents how warp drive cheats. However, being a book, this is not canon

Comment: In that book, the insignia represents how warp drive sidesteps relativistic mass dilation.  The top curve represents the energy required to continue accelerating at near-light speeds, which approaches infinity.  IF you could somehow exceed the speed of light, that would then work backwards (higher energy would result in you moving slower.  Time would also run in reverse.).  The lower curve represents how warp drive cheats.  However, being a book, this is not canon.

Comment: Thank you! I realize this is an old answer, but I've been trying to think of this meaning and the novel it came from for a week now.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to remember reading an article back in the early '70s that attributed some influence on the emblem to the constellation Aquila, the Eagle.  I can not attest to the accuracy of this, but there is some resemblance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its the USAF Space Command insignia prior to NASA.

http://www.afspc.af.mil/shared/media/photodb/web/2013/08/130821-F-AS983-002.jpg[image]

Comment: Intriguing, but do you have any sources to back it up?

Comment: I don't buy it.  The US Air Force Space Command was not formed until 1982.  So wouldn't be that this emblem seems to include some forms that resemble the UFP emblems?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out... it's an upside down harp. Occurred to me while watching this video.

Comment: Why would it represent a harp?

Comment: @Null An _upside down_ harp. To represent the fact that they have nothing whatsoever to do with harps.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know why. You can't prove it and they don't mention it, but, I always thought the insignia looks like the anarchist symbol.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchist_symbolism#mediaviewer/File:Circle-A_red.svg
Things such as, the non-interference principal, and the fact that Gene and company were looking to the future, it might be possible they saw this insignia as a mixed or hidden version of it. Purely a guess but merits pointing out. Spock's Vulcan beliefs also closely match voluntaryism. Most people won't know what that is without a little reading. Although that is totally contradicted by Gene's belief in a united earth future. Also maybe he saw the AA symbol somewhere? Now I'm being funny.

Comment: It may look like the "Anarchist symbol" but unfortunately you will need to provide a source connecting the two; otherwise this is only opinion-based.

Answer (score -5):

The insignia also refers to the arrowhead like shape of the warp field, as initially sketched and theorized, and later proven by Zepherin Cochran.

Comment: The warp fields we see on screens in TNG onwards are all either basically a distorted bubble shape or mostly conform to the ship.  Do you have a reference for warp fields being arrowhead-shaped at some point?

Comment: I wish I could. I remember seeing the diagram in a book (perhaps a novel). The arrowhead was sideways and one arc was more distinct than the other for a specific reason, referred to in the text.

Comment: Keith Wolvers above posted the same thing over a year ago.